# Doctrine custom hydrators with Zend Framework 2 - How to specify in config file?

Tags: php, configuration, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I've successfully created a custom Doctrine Hydrator, and can use it by calling the

```
$entityManager->getConfiguration()->addCustomHydrationMode('...', '...')
```

method.

However, I'm injecting dependencies into constructors via factories, so the entity manager isn't available in the classes themselves - which makes inheritance a bit more annoying (factory inheritance anyone?).

What I would prefer is to be able to configure my custom hydrators in the zf2 config file (where all the routes, services, other doctrine stuff etc is configured) - but I can't find any documentation on how to specify this.

1. Is this even possible?
2. What are the magic incantations necessary?

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to register hydrators in doctrine via configuration. For example to register the `DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject` hydrator, in your module configuration array which is loaded by `Application\Module::getConfig` you can add the following code.

```
'doctrine' => array(
    'configuration' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
            'customHydrationModes' => array(
                'DoctrineModule' => 'DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject',
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

This registers `DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject` under an hydration mode called *DoctrineModule*. Now you can obtain this hydrator from the entity manager.

```
$entityManager->newHydrator('DoctrineModule');
```

For more information about the DoctrineModule see https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/hydrator.md.

Answer (score 1):

Found the way to specify custom doctrine hydrators in the config file:

```
['doctrine']['configuration']['orm_default']['customHydrationModes']
```

From the class docs (\DoctrineORMModule\Options\Configuration):

> Keys must be the name of the custom hydration method and the value must be the class name for the custom hydrator